# Problems displaying array data for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having problems display data in datatables, if I put the array straight in like this it works

```
$.parseJSON("[[\"1\",\"New Zealand\",\"20\"],[\"2\",\"Australia\",\"30\"]]");
```

but when I do it using a variable it doesn't it says read the error docs https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4
I don't understand what's going on here

```
var self = this;
var data = $.parseJSON(self.model.get('shipping'));

// data is in this format [["1","New Zealand","20"],["2","Australia","30"]]

var intfreight = $('#edit-int-freight').DataTable(
{
    //"aoColumnDefs": [{ "aTargets": [ 2 ] }] ,
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
    ],
    data: data,
    columns: [  
        { title: 'id' },                    
        { title: 'country', searchable: true},                     
        { title: 'shipping_rate',  
            render: function (data, type, row) {                                
            return '$' + data;
        }},             
        { title: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false, render: function() {
            return '<a class="delete" href="#edit/delete-freight">Delete</a>';
        }}
    ]
});
```

Comment: I suspect that "self.model.get" is an asynchronous function, if that's the case, it won't return and you'll have to get the data from a callback function or a promise. What library is "self.model.get" ?

Comment: self.model.get('shipping') is a get acessor for a model in backbone. so it's just getting a value

Comment: If you console.log(self.model.get('shipping')), what's the output ? is it an object or a string ?

Comment: it's this value "[[\"1\",\"New Zealand\",\"20\"],[\"2\",\"Australia\",\"30\"]]"

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: This JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/23u5qou4/) suggests that there's something wrong with your data, are you perhaps getting nulls back from your server? Does this setting `defaultContent` help like here (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lkkbtwf7/)?